# Plot a continuous function in R

Tags: r, plot

How would I plot something like `y = a*b` in R, where `y` equals some constant and `a,b > 0`.

So `a*b=5` for example. Where it plots that line.

I've only ever seen passing in lists of values for `a` and `b` and plotting `y` from those values, not plotting a continuous curve.

```
f <- function(a,b) {a*b}
```

How would I do something like the following in R?

```
f <- function(a,b) {a*b = 5}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a *parametric* plot.  If you can't or don't want to solve for y in terms of x (y=5/x in this case), you can compute the values over a grid and ask R to draw the relevant contour line.  The `curve3d` function from the `emdbook` package provides a convenient wrapper for this task.

```
library(emdbook)
curve3d(x*y,sys3d="contour",levels=5,
        xlim=c(0,5),ylim=c(0,5))
curve(5/x,col=2,add=TRUE)
```

But it's actually not too hard to do in base R either:

```
xvec <- seq(0,5,length=51)
yvec <- seq(0,5,length=51)
z <- outer(xvec,yvec,"*") ## "*" is default but you could specify
                          ## any other _vectorized_ function of two
                          ## arguments ...
contour(xvec,yvec,z,levels=5)
```

If your function is *not* vectorized in x and y, you could (1) use `?Vectorize` to make it vectorized; (2) use `expand.grid` on your x and y vectors, `apply` your function, and collapse the vector of results back into a matrix; (3) use nested `for` loops; or (4) just give up and use `emdbook::curve3d` (that's what it's for).