# R: Plotting a function f(x,y)=c, where c increases in intervals of 1

Tags: r, function, plot, polar-coordinates

I have a function [image: psi] such that the R code: `x^{4/3})*(sin((4*y)/3)`. I want to plot this function for different values i.e.

```
x^{4/3})*(sin((4*y)/3)=0,
x^{4/3})*(sin((4*y)/3)=1, 
x^{4/3})*(sin((4*y)/3)=2
```

etc... onto the same graph.

One of the plots should look like this: [image: psi = 2]

How can I do this in R?

Comment: Polar plots do exist in R, both in base graphics and `ggplot2`. Even without the native format, one should be able to use basic geometry to convert from cartesian to polar. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried but none have worked, Desmos gives a good result but it doesn't allow values of r to the power of anything

Comment: What have you tried *in R*? See e.g. https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_polar.html ; https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_function.html ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082429/plot-a-heart-in-r/8082633#8082633

Comment: I haven't seen any examples of someone using two variable functions i.e. ```function(x,y)(x^{4/3}*sin(4*y/3))``` , they're all single variable functions

Comment: This is called a *parametric plot*: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996220/plot-a-continuous-function-in-r/22996608#22996608

Comment: Can't you solve this for x in terms of y, e.g. `x=(c/*(sin((4*y)/3)^(3/4)`  where `c` is the relevant contour?